# Atom or Molecule

Tags: homework-and-exercises

Surely, there must be a difference between atom and molecule. Could someone please explain to me the reason for it?

Comment: What, exactly, about the corresponding search results or Wikipedia articles is unclear to you?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort.

Answer (score 4):

A "molecule" is the assembly of at least two atoms.

So, the smallest part of every substance should be an atom.

Comment: If "A "molecule" is the assembly of at least two atoms." then what about Helium and Neon? How many atoms do they have in a molecule?

Comment: @Aniket should read this:
[link](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/11127)

Comment: How about this link.... http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/molecule :Which is true, which is not ?

Comment: It's the same definition isn't it ?

`The element helium is a one-atom molecule.`

[...]

`A molecule is the smallest particle in a chemical element or compound that has the chemical properties of that element or compound. Molecules are made up of atom s that are held together by chemical bonds. `

Comment: Yeah that is the exact definition and the most important difference of a molecule with an atom.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/molecule seems split with definitions on both sides. Personally I think it would make sense to include unbound atoms as molecules, otherwise there's no umbrella term to refer to the things bouncing around in a gas that aren't held together with van der waals forces.

Comment: @GordonAmable Your definition is incomplete. That is what I wanted to refer to. The definition of molecule is just not " the assembly of at least two atoms". There are more imp points and the definition you quoted in your previous comment shows you that.

Answer (score 1):

The idea that splitting material objects into smaller and smaller pieces infinitely did not seem plausible to some people.Therefore they came up with the idea that there must a smallest piece that is indivisible and Greeks named it atom.
Nowadays what we call an atom consists of smaller pieces and can definitely be split into pieces.
 This may seems like a contradiction to the fundamental idea of being indivisible.
 However we modified the Greek idea and call an atom as the smallest unit of matter which has well defined chemical properties. 
In other words, currently, atom is the bottom line of chemistry but not physics.
By the way, the atoms with different chemical properties are named as elements and grouped in the famous periodic table. 
One can of course bring atoms together to form molecules, clusters, solids etc. 
A molecule in particular is a collection of atoms bonded together chemically.
For example, nitrogen (N) is an atom, dinitrogen (N<sub>2</sub>) is a molecule that consists of two nitrogen atoms bonded chemically.
The air we breath consists of almost %80 dinitrogen gas. Not nitrogen atoms.